# Running JS file from command line

Tags: javascript

I have a file with a simple code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
            alert("I get "+i+" objects!");
        }
    </script>
```

When trying to run it from cmd

> Wscript.exe "alert.js"
>   I get an error Error of compilation Microsoft JScript supposed to have ';'

Is it error in the script itself?

I tried this way (removed html tags)
 `for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) { alert("I get "+i+" objects!"); }`

After that, running it I have error of compilation: Syntaxis error

Comment: U sure you don't wanna check on node JS?

Answer (score 2):

The script tags `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` aren't valid js. They are html.

You should remove them from alert.js

Answer (score 1):

remove the HTML tags, this should work

```
for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    alert("I get "+i+" objects!");
}
```

Comment: I tried this way (removed html tags)  for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
alert("I get "+i+" objects!");
}  After that, running it I have  error of compilation: Syntaxis error

Answer (score 0):

1. You should remove script tags.
2. Replace alert() with  WScript.Echo().
   like:

> for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
>      WScript.Echo("here is");
>   }

Note: alert is a method of the browswer's window object. The Window's scripting host does not supply such an object.

Comment: You paste the code above in your .js file? Its working fine at my end. Remember script tags are not include in .js file.

Comment: Yes, I made it exactly as you said.- just pasted the code above  for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) { WScript.Echo("here is"); }  but when I execute it I get the error syntaxis error 800A03EA  may be something wrong with my Wscript though

Comment: Yes, it is possible, another problem may be due to the double quotes could you please try to paste this code.
for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) { WScript.Echo('here is'); }

Comment: Changed " to ' - but still the result is the same. I have win 8